# Avoid user access by directly typing url NEXT js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I currently build an app with Next and React. I have routes like /checkout or /checkout/success that I do not want letting the user directly acessing to it by typing the url in the search bar

I want force the user to navigate along pages manually to acces to these routes but I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side code, check whether the user is authenticated or not. If the user is authenticated, then the flow is as usual if not, then redirect him to login page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I forgot to mention that there is no user/auth system for this part of the app

Comment: /checkout or /checkout/success pages might need some query params intruder for the page to function properly(which can be only be brought through the journey).
If the user directly types these URLs without those query params, the page might break.
So check for those params, If they are missing, redirect the user.